# Unable to display column total in ORACLE 11G

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, rollup

While executing this query, I'm getting the GRAND TOTAL column blank (ORACLE 11G).

QUERY :

```
select  NVL(TO_CHAR(APPROVER_EMPLOYEE_NAME), 'Grand Total') as EMPLOYEE_NAME,
SUM(ONE_DAY) one_day, 
SUM(TWO_DAYS) TWO_DAYS , 
SUM(THREE_DAYS) THREE_DAYS, 
SUM(ONE_DAY + TWO_DAYS + THREE_DAYS) TOTAL
from ic_request
group by rollup (APPROVER_EMPLOYEE_NAME);
```

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME          ONE_DAY       TWO_DAYS        THREE_DAYS     TOTAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc                      271            64      
xyz                       60            09               01      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grand Total              331            73               01
```

There is no value corresponding to 'abc' row and 'THREE_DAYS' column.
Can anyone please help to display the 'TOTAL' column, which sums up the row total >

Answer (score 3):

It's because `THREE_DAYS` column for the row `abc` is null. You can just use `COALESCE` to make the null to zero and the do the addition properly.

**Query**

```
select  NVL(TO_CHAR(APPROVER_EMPLOYEE_NAME), 'Grand Total') as EMPLOYEE_NAME,
SUM(COALESCE(ONE_DAY, 0)) one_day, 
SUM(COALESCE(TWO_DAYS, 0)) TWO_DAYS , 
SUM(COALESCE(THREE_DAYS, 0)) THREE_DAYS, 
SUM(COALESCE(ONE_DAY, 0) + COALESCE(TWO_DAYS, 0) + COALESCE(THREE_DAYS, 0)) TOTAL
from ic_request
group by rollup (APPROVER_EMPLOYEE_NAME);
```

Comment: It's not because "THREE_DAYS column for the row abc is null", but because in every single record either ONE_DAY or TWO_DAYS or THREE_DAYS is null. So ONE_DAY + TWO_DAYS + THREE_DAYS becomes null for every record, hence the null sums. Apart from this your answer is correct.